# copy files from azure file storage to azure website after release

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, azure-pipelines-build-task, azure-pipelines-release-task

I have files that need to be copied over to my website (azure website) after a deployment has been made.  usually these files are server specific (I have multiple different servers for different releases), and usually in the past, before i used azure, i just had a backup folder with these files and a powershell script that i ran after deployment that just copied those files right over.

Now that i'm moving to azure, i'd like to keep this functionality.  I'm interested in copying over these files into azure file storage, and then in my release task after azure website deployment, just copying from that file storage over into the site\wwwroot folder.   I'm not really seeing an easy way to do this. Is there a release task i can use with this in mind?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a release task i can use with this in mind?

Yes, we could use the  [Azure File Copy task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/azure-file-copy?view=vsts). I also do a demo to copy the zip file to the azure storage. It works correctly on my side. Fore more information, please refer to the screenshot.

[image]

[image]

**Note:** If you don't want to zip the files, you could remove the Archive File task.

**Test result:**

[image]

Comment: Hey @Tom here i guess you are copying file from local machine to blob storage, but is there a way to copy file from Azure File Storage to Azure VM cloud to cloud?

Comment: @NaveenKumar There is a task  [AzureFileCopy](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/blob/master/Tasks/AzureFileCopyV1/README.md) that could copy the blob storage to Azure VM.  But I am not sure whether there is a task could copy azure file storage to Auzre VM. If there is no related task, I think you could use blob storage to instead of file storage or you could use the command to copy the file storage to blob and then use Azure file copy task to copy it to Azure VM.